# convert data frame so that each unique transaction listed becomes a single row

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a data frame like this:

```
        trans_id   product_id
1          1          456
2          4          223
3          1          778
4          1          774
5          5          999
6          4          123
```

I need to convert it so that all trans_id are listed as a single row like this:

```
trans_id      V1       V2     V3
1            456      778   774
4            223      123
5            999
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add a secondary ID column. That's easy with `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package. Since "splitstackshape" also loads "data.table", it's easy to then convert to a wide format using `dcast.data.table`:

```
library(splitstackshape)
dcast.data.table(
  getanID(mydf, "trans_id"), 
  trans_id ~ .id, value.var = "product_id")
#    trans_id   1   2   3
# 1:        1 456 778 774
# 2:        4 223 123  NA
# 3:        5 999  NA  NA
```

The equivalent "dplyr"+"tidyr" approach would be something like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydf %>%
  group_by(trans_id) %>%
  mutate(id = sequence(n())) %>%
  spread(id, product_id)
```

Answer (score 3):

A base R option would be

```
reshape(transform(df, N= ave(trans_id, trans_id, FUN=seq_along)), 
               idvar='trans_id', timevar='N', direction='wide')
#   trans_id product_id.1 product_id.2 product_id.3
#1        1          456          778          774
#2        4          223          123           NA
#5        5          999           NA           NA
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
t(df %>% spread(trans_id, product_id))
```

+1 @Ananda Mahto answer for `tidy` and `dplyr`

Comment: Could you show the output you obtained?  I get 6 columns and 3 rows.

Comment: Care to post the output you're getting. I get a lot more `NA`s than expected with this.